# How to know if a client connected to a QTcpServer has closed connection?

Tags: c++, qt, networking, tcp, network-programming

I want to pass data from a particular location (Shared Memory) to client applications. A thread continuously polls the SHM for new data and as soon as it gets something, it passes it onto the clients.

There can be multiple instances of such client applications which will be connecting to my (`QTcpServer`) server.

I am planning to simply create a new `QTcpSocket` each time my server receives a new connection and store all those sockets in a vector. Later, on each successful poll, I will write the data to all the `QTcpSocket`'s stored in the vector.

But if a client drops a connection (closes his window) I need to know about it! Othewise I will keep writing to `QTcpSocket`'s that are no longer existing and end up crashing.

What is the solution here ?

There are only 2 signals in `QTcpServer` class:

```
Signals
void    acceptError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError socketError)
void    newConnection()
2 signals inherited from QObject
```

Comment: You will need some form of [TCP keep alive](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html) on your socket

Comment: Yeah, any idea how it could be dont in Qt ?

Answer (score 5):

You have a class that contains a vector or list of the sockets. So long as this class is derived from QObject, you can use the signals and slots of QTcpSocket to notify the class when it is disconnected.

So, I'd do something like this: -

```
class Server : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        Server();

    public slots:
        // Slot to handle disconnected client
        void ClientDisconnected(); 

    private slots:
        // New client connection
        void NewConnection();

    private:
        QTcpSocket* m_pServerSocket;
        QList<QTcpSocket*> m_pClientSocketList;
};

Server::Server()
{   // Qt 5 connect syntax
    connect(m_pServerSocket, &QTcpServer::newConnection, this, &Server::NewConnection);
}

void Server::NewConnection()
{
    QTcpSocket* pClient = nextPendingConnection();
    m_pClientSocketList.push_back(pClient);

    // Qt 5 connect syntax
    connect(pClient, &QTcpSocket::disconnected, this, &Server::ClientDisconnected);
}

void Server::ClientDisconnected()
{
    // client has disconnected, so remove from list
    QTcpSocket* pClient = static_cast<QTcpSocket*>(QObject::sender());
    m_pClientSocketList.removeOne(pClient);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set the [TCP KeepAplive](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html) option to the socket in this way:

```
mySocket->setSocketOption(QAbstractSocket:: KeepAliveOption, 1);
```

Comment: You may want to give a comment about what this does and why you think it might aid the situation in order to make your answer a bit more viable.